# How should I separate a string which contains slashes with a single slash?

Tags: c#

This is a sting like this:

```
string a = "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3";
```

I want to separate string a with '\', so write like this:

```
List<string> result = a.Split('\\').ToList();
```

But, result only contains ONE member:

```
{C: older1 older2 older3}
```

I want to have 4 members in result:

```
{C:,folder1,folder2,folder3}
```

So, how shold I do it?

Comment: What is `splite`? If you use verbatim string literal as `@"C:\folder1\folder2\folder3"` and use `Split()` method, you will get your answer as `C:, folder1, folder2, folder3` string array then you can use `String.Join` method if you want them as a one string. If you don't, just don't use `String.Join`.

Comment: I don't agree that this question is off-topic because "it was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error". The problem was that `String.Split` returned one instead of 4 strings. If his code was really using `splite` instead `Split` it would not even compile. So i've fixed this typo. The real issue  is clear if that is the string he has used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your sample string does not contain backslashes.

This string contains three:

```
string a = "C:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3";
```

or this:

```
string a = @"C:\folder1\folder2\folder3"; // google: verbatim string literal
```

`\f` is an [escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) for  formfeed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what if I just get a sting like this:   'string a = "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3"'   and I can't stop it sending to me. What can I do? Can I do some work to transfer its format?

Comment: If someone sends you a strink like that i am sure that he will inclzde the backslashes. Dont confuse it with the same string in a textfile. Those escape sequences work only in a string literal

Answer (score 0):

Define your string as

```
string a = @"C:\folder1\folder2\folder3";
```

so it does not takes backslash as special char.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what if I just get a sting like this: 'string a = "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3"'  and I can't stop it sending to me. What can I do? Can I do some work to transfer its format?

Comment: If the string you received (let's say from a text file for example ) is  "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3", Split('\\') will work correctly. The problem is that if you write  string a = "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3"; in a c# program it will interpret \f as a special character. The '\' is not treatet as escape character if you write @"C:\folder1\folder2\folder3".